# DynamoDB design for a booking system

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm designing a webapp booking system and am considering using a single table DynamoDB instead of a postgres RDS on AWS for storage. I have a fair bit of experience with relational databases, but am less experienced with NoSQL. Having read through a lot of the docs I understand access patterns are key to a NoSQL design and I can solve for just about all of them, but would appreciate any input.

**Key points**

- Small database (<5gb)
- Unknown user access volume (assume less than 100 at any one point in time)
- Scaling for volume or access is unlikely to be an issue given the user base

**3 main items (some attributes listed in parentheses):**

- Businesses (name, address, phone)
- Contacts (associated business, first name, last name, email, mobile)
- Bookings (associated business, associated contact, start datetime, end datetime)

**Current table design** (cut-down for ease of reading)

| Business Id (Pk) | Type (SK) | id(attr) | name (attr) | first name (attr) | start (attr) | end (attr) | requester (attr) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 |  |  | Walmart |  |  |  |  |
|  | Contact | 222 |  | Bob |  |  |  |
|  | Contact | 233 |  | Sally |  |  |  |
|  | Booking | 333 |  |  | 03-05-2023T01:30:00 | 04-05-2023T01:30:00 | 233 (sally) |
| 345 | - |  | Costco |  |  |  |  |
|  | Contact | 244 |  | Joe |  |  |  |
|  | Booking | 344 |  |  | 10-05-2023T01:30:00 | 10-05-2023T02:30:00 | 244 (joe) |
|  | Booking | 355 |  |  | 12-04-2023T10:00:00 | 10-04-2023T10:00:00 | 244 (joe) |

**Secondary Indexes**

- Id (attribute)
- Start (attribute)
- Requester (attribute)

**Access patterns:**

- Get business by id: getItem key {'Business Id': {'S': '123'})
- Get business contacts: getItem key {'Business Id': {'S': '123'},'Type': {'S':'Contact'})
- Get business bookings: getItem key {'Business Id': {'S': '123'},'Type': {'S':'Booking'})
- Get contact by id: query id ('Id': {'S':'222'})
- Get contact bookings: Unsure. For this request I know the PK, but need to filter returns where sk is booking and requester (att) is x.
- Get booking by id: query id ('Id': {'S':'222'})
- Search booking: Unsure. This is probably the hardest one. The use case here is the company whom I'm building the webapp for. They want to see upcoming bookings (regardless of business- pk) so they can allocate staff. I tried to address this with a secondary index to avoid a scan, but this might just be a table scan and I have to live with it.

I'm not sure if I am treating this too much like a relational database with the assignment if ids for contacts and bookings. Further maybe I'm looking at this wrong and instead these should be 3 separate tables, but I'm still thinking a single table makes sense as the data is hierarchical (a contact must belong to a business, and a booking must have a requester and a business).